# Adding vertical space inside a table

Tags: tables, spacing, border

I need some extra top padding for the row below header:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor, booktabs, tabularx, colortbl}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|X X X|}
\rowcolor{lightgray}
header & header & header \\
\addlinespace
test   & test   & test   \\
test   & test   & test   \\
test   & test   & test  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

outputs

[image]

So I have my vertical space, but the outer border is broken. What other options do I have?

Comment: Normally youn would use e.g. `header & header & header \\[10pt]`. However this will make the gray area taller.

Comment: That is not what I want.

Comment: If don't want it gray, in this particular case you could put in a blank row, and tweak its size using a negative number after its rowbreak, e.g., `header & header & header \\       &        &        \\[-1.5ex]`. Not sure that's the best way.

Comment: @frabjous Thanks for the suggestion. I see that it creates a partial boundary line overlap.

Comment: I don't see what you mean, but another idea would be to put some artificial vertical height in the row under the header: `\vphantom{\rule{1pt}{3ex}}test   & test   & test   \\ `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want a typographic strut, i.e., an object with depth and height but no width, which makes it invisible.

You are obviously free to vary the two parameters of the `\rule` that underlies the `\TBstrut` macro to suit your needs.

A final comment: Do give some serious thought to omitting the vertical rules entirely. Trust me, they won't be missed.

[image]

*Addendum*: If you don't want to "see" the black lines at the edges of the header row, I suggest you issue the instruction `\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}` at the start of that row and `\arrayrulecolor{black}` at the start of the next row, i.e., the first data row.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand\TBstrut{\rule[-0.7ex]{0pt}{3.2ex}} % "top-and-bottom" strut

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|X X X|}
\rowcolor{lightgray}
header & header & header\TBstrut \\
test   & test   & test   \\
test   & test   & test   \\
test   & test   & test  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. The output will be perfect in all PDF viewers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{NiceTabular}[width=\columnwidth,colortbl-like]{|X X X|}
\rowcolor{lightgray}
header & header & header \\
\RowStyle[cell-space-top-limit=3pt]{}
test   & test   & test   \\
test   & test   & test   \\
test   & test   & test  \\
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Do these packages have any downsides?

Comment: The main drawback of `nicematrix` is that it cannot construct tables spanning over several pages (as does `longtable` for instance). The main advantage is that it's possible to use it in conjunction with Tikz to achieve a wide range of effects. It also provides features dealing with mathematical matrices...

Answer (score 2):

With `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec = {|X X X|},
                      row{1}  = {bg=lightgray},
                      rowsep  = 1pt,
                      row{2}  = {abovesep=7pt}, 
                      }
header & header & header    \\
test   & test   & test      \\
test   & test   & test      \\
test   & test   & test      \\
    \hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]